# Disable apache2 service

Tags: apache2, services

I'm experiencing a very weird behavior of the **apache2** service in **Ubuntu 18.04** . I am unable to disable the service, using either systemctl or update-rc.d. I ran both `systemctl disable apache2` and `update-rc.d apache2 disable` but somehow after a reboot I can access 127.0.0.1.

I'm a long time Arch user and I recently switched to Ubuntu. Clearly I'm missing something here, does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Are you able to stop the service with `sudo service apache stop`?

Comment: I can. I want to disable it, so that it doesn't start at boot.

Comment: Seriously ? I need a script to disable a simple service ?!?!

Comment: `systemctl disable apache2` should disable the server permanently, i.e. across boot. Are you sure it is still running? You can verify that with `systemctl status apache2`. To see if it will start at the next boot, do `systemctl is-enabled apache2`.

Comment: Is the service name actually apache2? What is the output of 'sudo service --status-all'?  Does the list say "apache" or "apache2"?

Comment: The service name is apache2

Comment: `systemctl is-enabled apache2` says `disabled` however I can still access 127.0.0.1 after a reboot.

Comment: Are there still symlinks for apache2 inside /etc/systemd/system/ after running the systemctl disable command? If so, you could rename or delete the symlinks I believe to make this stop running at boot up.

Comment: No symlinks in /etc/systemd/system

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem solved itself somehow, in a weird way. If I disable the service through systemctl and reboot, I can still access localhost but only once. If I hit refresh I get the normal error message.

Comment: So it is simply a browser cache issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Omg like 2 of the last 3 days I've lost 2h+ on BROWSER CACHE WTF

Answer (score 0):

You could just run `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`